# DebugLog Format string is not a string literal

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, debugging, ios5

My code looks like

```
DebugLog(urlStr);
```

urlStr is an NSString
but I keep getting a warning saying

```
Format string is not a string literal
```

I got this code from a website.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DebugLog(s, ...) NSLog(s, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define DebugLog(s, ...)
#endif
```

Comment: What is DebugLog? Is a method you have created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: `DebugLog(@"%@", urlStr);`