# Using DebugLog() instead of NSLog()

Tags: ios

i want to use DebugLog() to print values instead of NSLog(). I believe DebugLog() is more efficient. But i am not able to use it in my project(doesn't appear in prompt). I believe we have to set something in Build settings for that. Does anyone have any idea about this?

Thanks.

Comment: Never heard of it before. Not sure it even exists. Docs suggest it doesn't exist also.

Comment: i think he is talking of dlog which we use at the time when the app is in release mode

Comment: Is debug log from some third party library? If you just want to use NSLog during debug use the macros.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

DebugLog() is not a supported method in objetice-c, if you want to implement it yourself, do something like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DebugLog(s, ...) NSLog(s, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define DebugLog(s, ...)
#endif
```

Taken from here:

[DebugLog Format string is not a string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9621143/debuglog-format-string-is-not-a-string-literal)

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#   define DLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__);
#else
#   define DLog(...)
#endif
```

Answer (score -2):

To call `NSLog` only for the debug build:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    NSLog("Debugging");
    //or any other statement
#endif
```

(This will be called only when the build configuration is 'debug' in your scheme)

Comment: This is required for every log in your source, other solutions allow you to define it centrally.

Comment: @jbat100:  Sure. I haven't mentioned otherwise. I was just telling how to do this. And it will work. How to implement it is up to the OP. Why would this deserve a down vote?